# SQLite define output field separator on a single line command

Tags: database, sqlite, output, separator

I need to use a **single command line** to fetch a set of records from a database.
If I do this:

```
$ sqlite3 con.db "SELECT name,cell,email FROM contacts"
```

I get output with a separator "|", where the output looks like this:

```
Alison|+12345678|alison@mail.com
Ben|+23456789|ben@mail.com
Steve|+34567890|steve@mail.com
```

Is there a way (**in single command line format like specified above**) to change the output field separator to something else, like ";;;" or something else or more unique. This is because the output occasionally get the character "|" inside the records, and it causes issues.

My desired result is:

```
Alison;;;+12345678;;;alison@mail.com
Ben;;;+23456789;;;ben@mail.com
Steve;;;+34567890;;;steve@mail.com
```

Or any other unique separator, which is not likely to be found inside the values.

(The command is executed on a Linux machine)

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`-separator` option](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) does what you want:

```sh
sqlite3 -separator ';;;' con.db "SELECT ..."
```

---

The only way to format the output so that you are guaranteed to not get the separator in the values is to quote all strings:

```sh
sqlite3 con.db "SELECT quote(name), quote(cell), quote(email) FROM contacts"
```

However, this would require you to parse the output according to the SQL syntax rules.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! The first option did the trick nicely.

Comment: Thank you, the SELECT quote(blah) helped me!